# Null value showing, despite if statement to get rid of it

Tags: php

I have the following code (see below) ... the if statement should be checking to see if $re_broker has a value (and is not null) ... however, the if statement is displaying the code with a "null" value.

I've tried an if statement with each of the following...

```
// isset($re_broker)
// $re_broker!=''
// !empty($re_broker)
// $re_broker!='null'
// $re_broker!=null
```

... but none have worked.  Any reason why this is happening? And how to fix it? I'm sure it is something simple, but I can't figure it out.

```
<?php
if(!empty($re_broker)) { ?>
     <div class="auth-box auth-outline broker">
          <div class="auth-txt"><?php echo $re_broker; ?></div>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($re_broker)` show?

Comment: Right after the first `if` before the bracket, add `echo "test";` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing the word `"null"` printed on screen, it means that `$re_broker` is a string containing `"null"`, and not actually `NULL`. A truly null variable should not evaluate to any string on `echo`. Investigate and perhaps post the code that sets the variable.

In PHP, a non-empty string evaluates to `TRUE`, regardless of what characters it holds. So `"false" == TRUE`, and `"null" == TRUE`. Can be a little tricky. And that is why your code block is running despite it being `"null"`

Also, you should simply use `isset()` or `is_null()` to test for NULL. Functions like `empty()` are not exactly just testing for NULL.

Comment: Worth noting that `isset` is considerably faster than `is_null`, and usually slightly faster than `$var !== null`

Comment: This worked...
 !isset($re_broker) && $re_broker!='null'

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the performance between `isset` and `is_null` - that would be a mico-optimisation that's probably premature. The more important note is that `isset` only works on variables, not on expressions.

Comment: @Jabbamonkey You are probably still on the wrong track. You should refrain from using a string "null" to represent null values. If a variable is null, it should really be null, not a string holding "null".